# Best practice for log retention using EFK in AWS EKS

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, amazon-eks, fluentd, efk

I have an AWS EKS cluster and have built a logging architecture using EFK: Elasticsearch, Fluentd, and Kibana. These are the specific settings.

Elasticsearch is deployed using StatefulSet and uses volumeClaimTemplates for volumeMounts in containers. Thus, an EBS volume is dynamically provisioned to serve this purpose.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data-pvc
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data-pvc
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      ...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data-pvc
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Gi
      storageClassName: gp2
```

Fluentd is deployed via DaemonSet, thus running on all nodes. Its container's volume is mounted in the hostPath, which means that it uses an EBS volume that is statically and directly attached to the EC2 instance.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.4.2-debian-elasticsearch-1.1
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Kibana is simply deployed via Deployment.

Now, I need to think about log retention, or rotation, policy, since I don't want all the logs eat up all the disk spaces.

1. The first question is, where are the actual logs stored? Is it in the dynamically provisioned EBS volume where container in Elasticsearch is mounted on? Or, is it in the EBS volume directly attached to the EC2 instance where container in Fluentd is mounted on?
2. Secondly, what is the best practice to set up a log retention policy? Say, I want to keep all the logs for 90 days. When a log becomes older than that, I want it to be directly saved to a pre-created S3 bucket, and be deleted from the EBS volume automatically. Can it be done utilizing the settings with regards to EFK, instead node-specific methods such as running a cron job in the node? If there is a way to do so, how should I modify the YAML files above?

Comment: Fluentd is a log router in that it routes logs to backends like ElasticSearch. It needs a buffer to temporarily store/filter/enrich logs before they are ultimately written to your configured backend. When the logs reach ElasticSearch, they are written to the EBS volumes associated with ElasticSearch. You'll need to look at the ElasticSearch documentation to see whether there is a way to archive logs older than 90 days to S3. You can do this with OpenSearch.

Comment: @JeremyCowan Thanks for your comment. Then, can I assume that Fluentd's storage is automatically cleaned up and does not necessarily store heavy logs for long time, since it is a mere buffer?

Comment: Yes, that's right.